# How in the real world I/O file strreams are used

Tags: c#

Hi I am a student do any body know were in real world I/O file streams are used?

Comment: Probably about 3 feet in front of you right now.  Review StreamReader and FileStream.

Comment: Just a heads up - I noticed you tagged your question with a language but it might be better (especially for people who just browse open questions like me) to put the language in the title.  The concept of I/O streams is pretty much language agnostic.  Are you asking specifically about c# streams or just I/O streams in general (and principles behind them)?

Answer (score 4):

They are used every time you want to read or write the file. It is most basic tool for file I/O in .net.

Comment: I agree, no reason for a downvote.  You answered the question with as much information that was provided.  If the OP wanted more detail they should have included such detail in the question, but that's a meta topic.